# Excel VBA - error handling and string searching

Tags: vba, excel, error-handling

Background:

I have a spreadsheet which is acting as an entry form. There are numerous entry fields, with a string in one cell denoting the title of the quantity and a value of the quantity of the cell below it.

Only some of these fields are mandatory. I am trying to write a macro to cycle through all mandatory fields and ensure there is a value present.

Important Variables:

MandatoryValues = array of strings containing the mandatory field titles

MandatoryCount = the number of mandatory fields

FindString = the field title as a string

r = the row of the field title

c = the column of the field title

Check_Value = the value of the cell beneath the field title which contains the desired value

Below is my code:

```
For i = 1 To MandatoryCount
    FindString = MandatoryValues(i - 1)
        With ActiveSheet.UsedRange
            Set Rng = .Find(What:=FindString, _
                            After:=.Cells(.Cells.Count), _
                            LookIn:=xlValues, _
                            LookAt:=xlWhole, _
                            SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                            SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                            MatchCase:=False)
            If Not Rng Is Nothing Then
                r = Rng.Row
                c = Rng.Column
                Check_Value = ActiveSheet.Cells(r + 1, c).Value
                data_type = TypeName(Check_Value)

                If data_type = "String" Then
                    If Check_Value = "" Then
                        If MsgBox(FindString & " Not Specified", vbOKOnly, "ERROR") = vbOK Then
                            Exit Sub
                        End If
                    End If
                End If

                If data_type = "Double" Then
                    If Check_Value = "" Then
                        If MsgBox(FindString & " Not Specified", vbOKOnly, "ERROR") = vbOK Then
                            Exit Sub
                        End If
                    End If
                End If

                If data_type = "Date" Then
                    If Check_Value = 0 Then
                        If MsgBox(FindString & " Not Specified", vbOKOnly, "ERROR") = vbOK Then
                            Exit Sub
                        End If
                    End If
                End If

                Else
            End If
        End With
Next i
```

For each loop, I search the UsedRange in the sheet for the title, and locate its position with .Find. This works fine. My problem is that as I am stepping through the code, I can see FindString, r and c changing with each iteration, but Check_Value is always empty. I feel like it's something dumb but I can't see it. Any suggestions?

Edit: I have added the code snippet

```
If Not Rng Is Nothing Then
            Address = Rng.Address
            Address_Below = Rng.Offset(1, 0)
```

The Address value updates for every iteration, and it is correctly finding the string in the sheet and retrieving the range. However, the Address_Below variable is always empty. I have no idea why this would be. Any ideas?

Comment: Forgot my declarations:     Dim FindString As String
    Dim Rng As Range
    Dim r As Long, c As Long
    Dim MandatoryValues As Variant
    Dim MandatoryCount As Integer
    Dim Check_Value As Variant

Comment: You should [edit] your post instead of adding valuable information in the comments.

Comment: `Check_Value` seems to rely on the `ActiveSheet` - are you sure the expected worksheet is active when this code runs?

Comment: Why using ActiveSheet.Cells when you already have a reference to the cell that match your search (Rng). You can use Rng.offset(1,0).Value

Comment: Your method of getting the value of the cell below the one found is sound,**as long as you don't have merged cells**. FWIW: you can skip the r and c variables and use this to get the value of the cell below: `Check_Value = Rng.Offset(1)`. Note: kudos for using the TypeName function and for reading the cell value into a variant. FYI, you might consider using some `And` and `Or` statements in your If blocks to reduce redundant code.

Comment: Are there any hidden rows between the Found cells and the supposed check value?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the the cell below the **MandatoryValues** (array of String) is the `Check_Value`, you should consider simplifying your code like below (with some tweaks):

```
With ActiveSheet.UsedRange
    'For i = 1 To MandatoryCount
    For Each FindString In MandatoryValues
        'FindString = MandatoryValues(i - 1)
        Set Rng = .Find(What:=FindString, _
                        After:=.Cells(.Cells.Count), _
                        LookIn:=xlValues, _
                        LookAt:=xlWhole, _
                        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                        SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                        MatchCase:=False)
        ' If error occurs you may use: What:=CStr(FindString)
        If Not Rng Is Nothing Then
            'r = Rng.Row
            'c = Rng.Column
            'Check_Value = ActiveSheet.Cells(r + 1, c).Value
            Check_Value = Rng.Offset(1, 0).Value ' <-- Remove .Offset() if not checking the cell below it
            'data_type = TypeName(Check_Value)
            Select Case TypeName(Check_Value)
                Case "String", "Double", "Date"
                    If Check_Value = "" Or Check_Value = 0 Then
                        If MsgBox(FindString & " Not Specified", vbOKOnly + vbExclamation, "ERROR") = vbOK Then Exit Sub
                    End If
                Case Else
                    Debug.Print """" & FindString & """ at " & Rng.Address & " is of type " & TypeName(Check_Value)
            End Select
        End If
    'Next i
    Next
End With
```

Comment: Thank you for this improved code, it is much cleaner. It seems to be functioning, except my problem remains. It is able to find the string in the sheet and return the range, but the Check_Value variable is always empty. I can't for the life of me figure out why.

Comment: You may want to use a Range object instead of using it's `.Value` or `.Text`. Can you put a Breakpoint [F9] on the line `Check_Value = ...` and do a manual check in Immediate window?

Comment: @JustinReiter Try running your code on a new, completely unformatted sheet with just one mandatory value.